# TCL Expect is injecting an extra null character to stdout

Tags: linux, tcl, expect

It seems that `expect` is adding an extra null character or something to stdout. For example:

```
$ expect -c 'spawn -noecho echo xyz; expect eof' | wc -c
5
$ echo xyz | wc -c
4
```

What is this extra character and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a null character.  You can use a tool like `xxd` to see exactly what output `expect` is producing:

```
$ expect -c 'spawn -noecho echo xyz; expect eof' | xxd
00000000: 7879 7a0d 0a                             xyz..
```

This shows that you are getting a standard CR/LF end-of-line terminator.  I'm guessing this is being produced because the stdout of your `echo` process is attached to a tty device, which often involves additional filtering to modify end-of-line characters and so forth (see `stty` for details).

You can disable this behavior by putting the tty in `raw` mode, like this:

```
$ expect -c 'set stty_init raw; spawn -noecho echo xyz; expect eof' |   wc -c
4
```

Comment: I like `od -c`, it's a bit more friendly